# Web essentials throwing warning with multiple bootstrap columns

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap-3, web-essentials

When I use the following code, it works as intended but Web Essentials (2013 for Update 2) shows an error: Bootstrap: Sum of columns of type col-xs-12 must not exceed 12. my intent is show only one column in the xs model.Any suggestions?

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
            DIV1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
           DIV2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
            DIV3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well">
            DIV4
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically, your classes are correct and should produce the results you want.  However, the `col-xs-12` is actually unnecessary in your case (and perhaps that's what Web Essentials is balking at, though it still seems to me to be an incorrect error).

Since Bootstrap 3 is mobile-first, the default behavior is that everything is 100% the width of the container **up** to the point that it reaches a breakpoint that has a specified col class.  For example, if you removed the col-xs-12 and col-sm-6, then everything up to the md breakpoint (at 992px by default) would be 100% of the container width.

What happens is that every col class applies 15px of padding left/right.  Then, at each of the breakpoints, the media-queries apply the percentage width to the columns.  For example, if you have col-lg-3, and nothing else, the column will get the padding no matter how wide the viewport is.  If the viewport happens to be 1200px or larger, the media-query for that breakpoint adds a rule that sets the col-lg-3 to a width of 25%.

So, what this means is that you can make your markup a little more concise, and as long as you specify at least one col-*-* type class for your column, it will align nicely in your grid.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Can you tell I'm a noob with Bootstrap?  What would be the proper markup for this code to have 4 cols for lg, 3 cols for md and 2cols for sm?  Just remove this col-xs-12?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'd do (remove the col-xs-12 from each div).  That will result in: 1 column up to 767px, 2 columns beginning at 768px, 3 columns at 992px and 4 columns at 1200px.